# My cat is doing a strange move with his mouth

Tags: cats

My cat had a problem a couple of months ago, and ate almost nothing for a few days.

He started to move his mouth in a weird way, as if the right side of his lips was hurting or as if some food were stuck in his teeth. It's like he was chewing something, producing a "smoosh-smoosh" sound.

We went to the vet, and she didn't see any problem into his mouth. No inflammation of the gums, no wound, no tooth decay. She concluded that he had nausea, because he was drooling a little at this time.

Now, he looks perfectly OK and eats normally, but he still does his strange move two or three times a day, especially after he eats his kibbles.

Should we worry? Could it be just a nervous tic? What solution(s) would you suggest?
Thanks in advance for your help! :)

[image: video (gif) of the cat with his mouth problem]

(This cat isn't actually talking)

Comment: if this continues you should take your cat back to the vet,it looks to me like your cat might have a bad tooth,remember you are the one that know your cat best and if you think something is wrong you take him to the vet.

Answer (score 1):

I would at least start with maybe just calling your vet’s office and explain what is going on and then see what they recommend <3. Then they can at least let you know if they think he should be seen again or not too. I hope all turns out well and that it’s nothing of concern <3. Beautiful cat btw, I have one who looks almost just like him :).